# Insert timestamp parameter into scrapy request right before it executes

Tags: scrapy, screen-scraping

I'm trying to get some data from an ajax based site where I have to get the public page and grab some ids from there so I can then simulate the ajax request to the server.

The problem is the second request requires a timestamp parameter. It looks something like:

```
    https://sub.domain.com/id/?z=9999999999
```

Where the z parameter is the UNIX time up to the second. After doing some testing, it turns out that the request is only available for a few seconds. If the timestamp isn't in that range, the server throws a 404.

Scrapy uses a generator to iterate over the requests, so if I'm creating a few dozen requests and on top of that I have the 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY' parameter set to wait a couple seconds between requests, that means the requests take a while between being created and when they are actually executed, so by then the timestamp has already expired and I get an error page.

My question is. Is there a way to add the parameter right before the actual request is executed? or alternatively, is it possible to execute a request on the spot instead of yielding it to the generator?.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to add the parameter right before the actual request is executed?

Yes, a custom [DownloaderMiddleware `process_request`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.7/topics/downloader-middleware.html#scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.DownloaderMiddleware.process_request) is designed for that purpose

> is it possible to execute a request on the spot instead of yielding it to the generator?

Yes and no; yes, because it's python, you can do what you'd like, but no, because if you just use `urllib` or `requests` or whatever, you completely circumvent all the Scrapy benefits, including your aforementioned `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` setting. You may be able to use the [`priority=` kwarg](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.7/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request) to tell Scrapy about the time sensitivity of the `Request`, but ultimately whether it is able to get that `Request` scheduled and executed within the time window of the timestamp is dependent upon how many of those there are in the queue.

I would try your first approach, by rewriting the timestamp, rather than trying to expedite an existing one -- especially if those timestamps are not meaningful to the server (that is, all they're doing is `now() - query.z` for validity, and not `select * from whatever where z = query.z`)